# Changing element visibility just before form submitting in Safari doesn't work sometimes

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4, safari

Here is the html-element (in its original state) I'm using to display a loading spinner throughout the app (using mostly Bootstrap classes):

```
<div id="loadSpinner" class="overlay d-flex justify-content-center invisible">
  ...
</div>
```

Here is the form in view (Rails 6):

```
  <%= form_with(url: result_path, 
      method: "patch", local: true) do |f| %>

    ...

    <%= f.submit "Finish", class: "btn btn-success btn-lg my-3",
        onclick: "finish();" %>

  <% end %>
```

Here is the 'finish()' js-function where the loading spinner is showing up:

```
function finish() {
  ...
  document.querySelector('#loadSpinner').classList.remove('invisible');
}
```

It works totally fine in Chrome and Firefox, but the loading spinner sometimes isn't displayed in Safari.

I've added some logs (`console.log(document.querySelector('#loadSpinner'))` after the 'invisible' class removal) and can see that the 'invisible' class is actually deleted before submitting. So the js-code works fine, but the spinner just doesn't show up.

Also, I've tried to add a 'visible' class after the removal of the 'invisible' one - the issue is still here.

Does somebody know why it happens in Safari?

I have an assumption that in fact the submitting happens somehow before the 'invisible' class is actually removed, but I don't know the way to check and fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, Safari needs a small delay before form submitting.

So the solution is the following.

1. Change the submit button in the form to the simple button:

```
<%= form_with(url: result_path, 
    method: "patch", local: true) do |f| %>

...
    
<%= button_tag "Finish", type: "button",
          class: "btn btn-success btn-lg my-3",
          onclick: "finish();" %>

<% end %>
```

2. Submit data with a small delay:

```
function finish() {
  ...
  document.querySelector('#loadSpinner').classList.remove('invisible');
  
  // submit form
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.querySelector('form').submit();
  }, 300);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Rails UJS you can use the `ajax:beforeSend` and `ajax:complete` events to toggle a spinner:

```
<%= form_with(url: result_path, method: "patch", remote: true, class: 'spinner-form') do |f| %>
```

```
let form = document.querySelector('#myForm');
let spinner = document.querySelector('#loadSpinner');

document.addEventListener('ajax:beforeSend', (event)=>{
  if (!event.target.matches('.spinner-form)) return;
  spinner.classList.remove('invisible');
});

document.addEventListener('ajax:complete', (event)=>{
  if (!event.target.matches('.spinner-form)) return;
  spinner.classList.add('invisible');
});
```

If you're doing it yourself you want to prevent the default event handler:

```
<%= f.submit "Finish", class: "btn btn-success btn-lg my-3",
        id: "myButton" %>
```

```
let btn = document.querySelector('#myButton');
let spinner = document.querySelector('#loadSpinner');

btn.addEventListener('click', (event)=>{
  let form = event.target.form;
  event.preventDefault();
  spinner.classList.add('invisible');

  fetch(form.action)
    .then((response)=>{
       spinner.classList.remove('invisible');
     });
});
```

If this is not an XHR (ajax) request then there is no way this will work as script execution halts when the page is reloaded.

Comment: It's not ajax. I have to keep it in 'local: true'.
Anyway, what does that have to do with Safari?

Comment: Not very much. I doubt what you're doing actually works reliably in any browser as it's conceptually broken.

Comment: Why? I thought onclick js-functions have to be executed before the actual submitting. And I can't see the issue in other browsers.

Comment: Unless your function is actually blocking like if it for example calls `alert` or you stop the event default the form is still going to submit and it's really just a timing issue. You probably just haven't discovered that it's broken yet on the other browsers...

Comment: Is there a way to postpone the submitting (in order to have time to execute the onclick-function)?

Comment: Yes. Use a real event handler instead of onclick. Prevent the default with `event.preventDefault()` - do your thing and then trigger the form submission with `event.target.form.submit()`.